# WPF isn't binding ComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, styles, selecteditem

I already search widely, but I can't find any solution to my case.

I have several ComboBox's at my project and I was searching for an AutoComplete solution, then I found a good one and applied in my project, I applied solution's style as well to all ComboBox in my project.

After that, SelectedItem stopped working, some one can help me ?

My Combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

My style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnEdit" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" BorderThickness="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="5,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3,3,23,3" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                    <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome Margin="4,6,4,6" CornerRadius="4">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" />
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**UPDATE**

My ToggleButton

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource LabPetsStandardColor}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
            <Path.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LabPetsStandardColor}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LabPetsPressedStandardColor}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My TextBox

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#00FFFFFF" Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                    <ScrollViewer.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                        </Style>
                    </ScrollViewer.Style>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Some, please, can help me ?

**UPDATE 2**

Found a hack, not the perfect solution, but kind of works...

If I insert property `SelectedValue` and the value `Owner.OwnerTypeId`, it works like a charm... But, it's right this?

My Combobox now:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType}" SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

This is a solution, not that I like it, but it's a solution...
Some one can answer why `SelectedItem` isn't working as it should ?

Obs.: When I change the selection, `SelectedItem` works, just doesn't work when I load my view.

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, it's worked like I said, but the problem is that WPF is hitting 4 times at my ViewModel, so I changed my `ComboBox` a little:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType}" SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

So, now, WPF just search the `OwnerTypeId` and when I change an item, WPF just hits 2 times.

**UPDATE 4**

Ok, another strange finding...
In another ComboBox, with the same properties, except `SelectedValue`, it's working perfect... I can't understand what is happening.

**UPDATE 5**

Sorry about that, I forgot to post my models.

Model Owner:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string FormatedPhone
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Phone == null)
                return string.Empty;

            switch (this.Phone.Length)
            {
                case 11:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                case 12:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                default:
                    return this.Phone;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string FormatedCellPhone
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.CellPhone == null)
                return string.Empty;

            switch (this.CellPhone.Length)
            {
                case 11:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                case 12:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                default:
                    return this.CellPhone;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual OwnerType OwnerType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    public Owner()
    {
        this.OwnerType = new OwnerType();
        this.Animals = new List<Animal>();

        this.ErrorList = new StringBuilder();
    }
```

Model OwnerType:

```
public class OwnerType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    public OwnerType()
    {
        this.Owners = new List<Owner>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It stopped working just after you altered the Template? Just notice something, try setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = True`

Comment: Another thing: try using `ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"`.  (I have noticed that MSDN's documentation of Named Parts is riddled with mistakes.)

Comment: Tico, if I put `True` to `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`, doesn't work right, ComboBox doesn't select the right Item, just select the first.

Comment: McGarnagle, i'll try it.

Comment: None of the attempts worked. :P

Comment: You cannot define SelectedItem and SelectedValue both bindings together, combobox will not work correctly, there is a bug in combobox which makes it loose value of one of the properties.

Comment: We're missing some info -- can you post the view-model property definition (and any relevant class definitions) for `OnwerTypes` and `Owner`?

Comment: @McGarnagle, models added.

Comment: Thanks - should I assume you have all the `INofityPropertyChanged` in there, and left it out for brevity?

Comment: One more typo:  I think you must have `Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"` and not `Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"`.

Comment: Is the `SelectedItem` the same reference in memory as one of the items in the `ItemsSource`? I recently answered [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20706990/302677), and so this was the first thing that came to mind when reading your question.

Comment: @McGarnagle, about `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you are right, it's there and I didn't insert because isn't necessary, and about `Style` or `Template`, need to be this, because I override the `ComboBoxTextBox` template, if I put in `Style` property, will be throw an error.

Comment: @Rachel, no, `ItemsSource` is a `List<OwnerTypes>` and `SelectedItem` is `Owner.OwnerType`.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte That could be your problem then. Try binding `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`, or overwriting the `.Equals()` of `OwnerType` to ensure two objects are considered equal if their `Id` property matches. A third option is to set `Owner.OwnerType` with something like `OwnerTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Owner.OwnerTypeId)` so they're the same reference in memory

Answer (score 15):

Your `SelectedItem` binding isn't working because WPF compares the `SelectedItem` to the items in the `ItemsSource` by the `.Equals()` method, which by default compares by reference. And the instance in memory containing your `SelectedItem` is not the same instance in memory as one of the items in your `ItemsSource`

There are 3 ways to handle this.

- First, as you've already discovered you can bind `SelectedValue` to a value type property on your item, and set `SelectedValuePath`.

  ```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId}" 
            SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            />
  ```

  This is usually the solution I go with because it's often easiest
- Second, you could ensure your `SelectedItem` is set to the same reference in memory as one of the `ItemsSource` items. Depending on the application design, this isn't a bad choice either.

  ```
  public class Owner()
  {
      public int OwnerTypeId { get; set; }

      public OwnerType OwnerType
      {
          get 
          { 
              return StaticClass.OwnerTypes
                  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == this.OwnerTypeId);
          }

          set
          {
              if (value != null)
                  OwnerTypeId = value.Id;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- And last of all, you could override the `.Equals()` method on the `OwnerType` object so it considers the two values equal if the `Id` properties are the same.

  ```
  public override bool Equals(object obj) 
  { 
      if (obj == null || !(obj is OwnerType)) 
          return false; 

      return ((OwnerType)obj).Id == this.Id); 
  }
  ```

  I usually try to avoid this method unless I know I'll always want to compare this object's equality by the `Id` property only, but sometimes this is the best way to go.

  Also, its good practice to override `.GetHashCode()` whenever you overwrite `.Equals()`.

As a side note, you usually don't want to be binding both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`. They are two different ways of setting the same thing, and you can get unexpected results by binding both of them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure that the way WPF works, because I use, in the whole project, the same way, `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` in different memory instances... As I update the question, in others part of the project, `SelectedItem` works, just on this one don't...

Comment: I couldn't know for sure unless I saw the other code that you have working, but the most common cases for that working is if you are binding to value types instead of reference types, or your `SelectedItem` gets set to an existing item from the `ItemsSource` collection instead of creating a new item. I know for sure this is the way WPF works though, because I've ran into this issue myself many times in the past :)

Comment: Adding IEquatable to the data worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a Template binding of selectedValue of comobox. Because you have overriden the control template and placed your own TextBlock to display the selected value. Now when the value is selected from the UI control Template takes care of displaying it. but it is not setting the value to the SelectedValue or SelectedItem.

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3,3,23,3" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" Text="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}"/>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the bindings, and break down what they say:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          />
```

So this means:

1. The items in the list are retrieved from the property "OwnerTypes".
2. The *selected item* will be bound to the property "OwnerType" *inside* the instance of the property "Owner".

Since there is no binding applied to `SelectedValue`, the `SelectedValuePath` will be completely ignored.  Note the [definition of SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets the path that is used to get the SelectedValue from the SelectedItem.

So let's omit #3 for now.  Working with #1 and #2, let's assume that the property "OwnerTypes" is of type `List<OwnerTypeDef>`.  This implies that the type `OwnerTypeDef` is the same type as the property "OwnerType" inside "Owner" property.  With this setup --

```
public class OwnerDef : INotifyPropertyChanged   // TODO implement INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public OwnerTypeDef OwnerType
    {
        get { return _ownerType; }
        set
        {
            if (_ownerType == value)
                return;
            _ownerType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private OwnerTypeDef _ownerType;
}

public class OwnerTypeDef : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
                return;
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _name;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (_id == value)
                return;
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private int _id;
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<OwnerTypeDef> OwnerTypes
    {
        get { return _ownerTypes; }
        set { _ownerTypes = value; }
    }
    private List<OwnerTypeDef> _ownerTypes = new List<OwnerTypeDef>
        {
            new OwnerTypeDef { Name = "foo", Id = 1, },
            new OwnerTypeDef { Name = "bar", Id = 2, },
            new OwnerTypeDef { Name = "baz", Id = 3, },
        };

    public OwnerDef Owner
    {
        get { return _owner; }
        set
        {
            if (_owner == value)
                return;
            _owner = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private OwnerDef _owner = new OwnerDef();
}
```

-- the binding works for me.  The property "OwnerType" inside "Owner" gets updated when I change the selection in the UI.

**Edit**

Let's look at the other scenario, where you use `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue`.  In this case, we are binding the selected *value* to "Owner.OwnerTypeId" (an integer).  We'll use `SelectedValuePath=Id`, which tells the framework to look for the "Id" property in the selected item (which is `OwnerDef.Id`, an `int`).  Therefore, we'll have to add a matching `int` property in the `OwnerDef` class, call it "OwnerTypeId".  XAML in this case would be:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          />
```

With this setup the binding is updating the "OwnerTypeId" correctly.

**Edit #2**

It's also possible use both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`, so that both the "OwnerType" and "OwnerTypeID" properties get updated.  Make sure to use `TwoWay` bindings (in Update #3 above they are the default OneWay):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OwnerTypes}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId,Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType,Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          />
```

This setup updates *both* the "OwnerTypeId" *and* the "OwnerType" properties when I select an item in the combo box.

Comment: As I said on update 4:

`**UPDATE 4**

Ok, another strange finding... In another ComboBox, with the same properties, except SelectedValue, it's working perfect... I can't understand what is happening.`

So, I understand your answer, but I'd like to keep working that way, if it's possible.

Comment: this way works, but isn't the right way, because I need to assign, or load, `OwnerType` when I commit to DB and with `SelectedValue` I don't set anything before I commit.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte but in update #3, the `SelectedValue` binding is `OneTime`, so of course that is not going to get updated.  You only need to use `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem`, not both of them.  Just set the `OwnerTypeId` from the `Owner` setter (probably easiest), or vice versa.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte I tried using both `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` and it seems to work -- see Edit #2 above.  Could the problem just be that your Update #3 is using one-way bindings?

Comment: that way it works, even in `OneWay` binding, but my doubt is why isn't working without `SelectedValue`? 'Cause all other ComboBox's works just with `SelectedItem`.