# Combobox binding itemsource to custom list and selecteditem to an instance of that list doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, selecteditem

I tried really different ways to make my combobox working but I'm still stuck :(

Here is a very simplified version of my app : (just edited, sorry for mistakes)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Grades}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson.MyGrade}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

And the code behind :

```
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private Grade myGrade;
    public Grade MyGrade
    {
        get { return myGrade; }
        set
        {
            if (myGrade != value)
            {
                myGrade = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyGrade");
            }
        }

    }

    //-- INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
public class Grade
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private int prop;
    public int Prop
    {
        get { return prop; }
        set
        {
            if (prop != value)
            {
                prop = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop");
            }
        }

    }

    //-- INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }

    private Person selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedPerson != value)
            {
                selectedPerson = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Grades = new ObservableCollection<Grade>();

        Grades.Add(new Grade() { Name = "Grade 1", Prop = 1 });
        Grades.Add(new Grade() { Name = "Grade 2", Prop = 2 });

        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "guy 1", MyGrade = Grades[0] });
        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "guy 2", MyGrade = Grades[0] });
        People.Add(new Person() { Name = "guy 3", MyGrade = Grades[1] });
    }

    //-- INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
```

The problem is that the combobox is still empty when I select an item in the listview.
The itemsource is OK (If I click on the combobox, I can see "grade 1" and "grade 2").
I think there is something missing to tell "the `Person.Grade` is part of the `Grades` list" but I cannot find what.

Hope you can help me ;)

Comment: Is the `SelectedItem` the exact same reference in memory as the item in the `ItemsSource`? By default, WPF will compare the item by reference, so this could be your problem. If they are different, I recommend using `SelectedValue` or possibly overwriting `.Equals()`. See [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/) for an example :)

Comment: I think the problem comes from something like that, I don't think the selecteditem and itemssource are from same reference. I will test that tonight and let you know ;)

Comment: Really really thanks !! the equals override method saved me :) :)

Comment: Glad that worked out for you :) I posted it as an answer below in case anyone else is looking to solve the same problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the `SelectedItem` the exact same reference in memory as the item in the `ItemsSource`?

By default, WPF will compare the `SelectedItem` to the items in the `ItemsSource` by reference, and if they're not the same reference in memory, it will return no matching item.

If you are unable to do this in your code, the most common workarounds are to either:

- Bind the `SelectedValue` to a value type instead of a reference type, and set the `SelectedValuePath`

  ```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Grades}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPerson.MyGrade.GradeId}" 
            SelectedValuePath="GradeId"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
  ```
- Or override the `.Equals()` to ensure the two objects are considered equal when specific properties match, as opposed to being considered equal when the reference in memory matches.

  ```
  public override bool Equals(object obj) 
  { 
      if (obj == null || !(obj is Grade)) 
          return false; 

      return ((Grade)obj).GradeId == this.GradeId); 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

A couple things, first you are binding to `Grade` and your property is called `MyGrade`.  Second you are instantiating different objects for grade in the `Grades` list and using different objects to assign to each person, you want to use the same objects if you want them to map correctly, something like this:

```
Grades.Add(new Grade() { Name = "Grade 1", Prop = 1 });
Grades.Add(new Grade() { Name = "Grade 2", Prop = 2 });

People.Add(new Person() { Name = "guy 1", MyGrade = Grades[0] });
People.Add(new Person() { Name = "guy 2", MyGrade = Grades[0] });
People.Add(new Person() { Name = "guy 3", MyGrade = Grades[1] });
```

Lastly you might want to make the Grades collection an `ObservableCollection` as well if you are going to bind it to the UI.  Also it seems a bit odd that your `RaisePropertyChanged` doesn't take in the name of the property.

There may be other mistakes as well but that is what jumped out to me right away.

Comment: Yup, you want `Grades` (in `MainWindow` to be an `ObservableCollection`). Also, you need to be raising `INotifyPropertyChanged` events for it too. The `Grades` property *is* being set but the binding is not being notified to look for the new collection.

Comment: Thanks for the mistakes :) I wrote my "simplified app" too much fast ... Unfortunately, the problem persists. I will edit my post with the corrections

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have no binding errors in the first place. You can verify this by opening up the output window in Visual studio and check you have no errors messages relating to binding expressions.

You should be able to easily spot these because the error message will contain the following text: **BindingExpression path error**

As an alternative approach why don't you try and bind the ComboBox selected item directly with the selected item from the ListView.

Below is a sample snippet of how one would achieve this:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="listView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Grades}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.MyGrade, ElementName=listView}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but I don't have binding errors.
I don't see the point of binding the listview item directly oO?

Comment: The previous reply was to try to bypass the property altogether and check if the combobox would be updated when selecting an item from the list view. If that was the case then there would be something wrong in the viewmodel.

I managed to replicate your scenario using the code provided. You are omitting the interface INotifyPropertyChanged from your class definitions. I do not know if you omitted these for brevity but if these are removed you will get your exact problem.

Comment: Change your class definitions as below:

`public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged`
`public class Grade : INotifyPropertyChanged`
`public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged`